# Groovy and the Metaclass

Tags: reflection, groovy, mocking, metaclass

I am attempting to use the metaclass to overwrite a static method in a test.

The method is:

```
org.boon.HTTP.jsonRestCallWithHeaders
```

It it is a Java class, and it is beyond my control.

The declaration is:

```
public static Response jsonRestCallWithHeaders(
            final String url,
            final Map<String, ?> headers
    )
```

I am attempting to overwrite the method with a closure via:

```
HTTP.metaClass.static.jsonRestCallWithHeaders =  { String url, Map<String, ?> headers ->
            if (url.path?.contains('/quotes')) {
                [prop1:value1,
                        prop2: value2 ] as JSON }
```

However, when it hits that redirect request it doesn't attempt to rewrite the method. It initializes the HTTP class, and attempts to call the HTTP.get function.

**My question is:** Why is this definition for the jsonRestCallWithHeaders method calling the HTTP::get static method?

A picture of the stacktrace:
[image]

I am using Groovy 2.1.9, Grails: 2.3.8. The code is being run within a test environment.

Comment: There are several things in your description that don't make any sense to me so I can't try to answer your question but it is peculiar that you are using Groovy 2.3.6 with Grails 2.3.8.  We shipped Grails 2.3.8 with Groovy 2.1.9 and that is the only version of Groovy that is supported with Grails 2.3.8. Have you built your own release or done something else to replace the version of Groovy in your copy of Grails?

Comment: I'll change this to Groovy 2.1.9 since they're bundled.

Comment: Were you somehow using Groovy 2.3.6 with Grails 2.3.8?

Comment: I don't think I was since I had Grails 2.3.8 configured. Groovy 2.3.6 was installed via GVM as the only Groovy implementation so I assume they were seperated.

Comment: Right.  That makes sense then.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Any thoughts on the issue it's self? It looks like to me that it's trying to resolve the property "metaClass" on the Java class.

Comment: I don't know.  What you have there should work but to troubleshoot you might try replacing `HTTP.metaClass` with `HTTP.getMetaClass()` or `HTTP.class.metaClass` or `HTTP.class.getMetaClass()`.  What those yield might or might not shed some light on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the following and it works:

```
HTTP.getMetaClass().static.jsonRestCallWithHeaders =  { String url, Map<String, ?> headers ->
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure but at a glance I think this is probably a bug that we should fix.  If you like, file a JIRA at https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY.

Comment: For me it also works. But it fails when `metaClass` is used instead of `getMetaClass()`. Why?

Comment: @Opal See my comment immediately above yours.

Comment: I saw it. Just didn't realize that this is the bug You thought of. Thanks!